# Meu :hover nao estam funcionando!

Tags: css-hover

Estou querendo colocar um background no meu botao ao passar o mouse, mas nao esta funcionando. Vou postar o codigo aqui.

Login Page

## Create an account

OR

```
    <form action="#" target="_blank">
        <label for="name">
            <span>Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        </label>

        <label for="email">
            <span>Email</span>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
        </label>

        <label for="password">
            <span>Password</span>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="signup_button">

    </form>

</main>
<section class="images">
    <img src="assets/mobile (1).svg" alt="Mobile">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

.signup_button{
cursor: pointer;
width: 50%;
margin-top: 4rem;
border-radius: 32px;
border: none;
background: #6c63ff;
color: white;
font-size: 1.1rem;

}

.signup_button :hover{
background: #1b2029;

}

Answer (score -3):

apenas não coloque espaço antes do :hover que vai dar certo. A classe é junto com o :hover

sintaxe: classe:hover

.signup_button:hover{ background: #1b2029;}